# Question about RouteData and ValueProvider on Asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have one doubt

To use this sentence: `filterContext.RouteData.Values["MyRouteValue"]` the key should be declared in a Route in the route table right?

I mean, should be in the route table something like: `{MyRouteValue}/`

If i have a request like /Controller/Action?MyRouteValue=XXXXXXX  im getting null from `filterContext.RouteData.Values["MyRouteValue"]`. This means that if i want to get the value i have to use filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("publicationUrlTitle").AttemptedValue istead?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Jose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To use this sentence: filterContext.RouteData.Values["MyRouteValue"]
>   the key should be declared in a Route in the route table right?

Yes.

> If i have a request like /Controller/Action?MyRouteValue=XXXXXXX im
>   getting null from filterContext.RouteData.Values["MyRouteValue"]. This
>   means that if i want to get the value i have to use
>   filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("publicationUrlTitle").AttemptedValue
>   istead?

Yes, use `ValueProvider` or read it from `filterContext.HttpContext.Request["MyRouteValue"]`. The advantage of using ValueProvider is that it looks in many places: route data, GET query string parameters, POST parameters, custom value providers such as a JSON value provider in ASP.NET MVC 3, ...

Just be careful by  when you access the `.AttemptedValue` property as you might get a `NRE` if the `MyRouteValue` is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug all routeValues, I've made a filter that copies all action parameters from the action method to the routedata values table:

```
public class CopyActionParametersToRouteData : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller == null)
            return;

        foreach (var actionParameter in filterContext.ActionParameters) {
            if (controller.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey(actionParameter.Key))
                continue;
            controller.RouteData.Values.Add(actionParameter.Key, actionParameter.Value);
        }
    }
}
```